# Releasing objects

Tags: objective-c, ios

I release objects created by @property directive in dealloc method like this

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [object release], object = nil;
}
```

I have two questions.

1. Is dealloc method the right place for releasing object generated by @property ?
2. Is it a good practice to set objects to nil ?

Comment: see this post for memory Handling http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/efficient-memory-handling-in-uiviewcontroller-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a good practice to set the pointer to direct to nil after releasing the object. The reason is that if you'd try to access value of that object in future after the object gets deallocated, you'll try to access a garbage value (it's called a dangling pointer) and your application would crash. But if the pointer is set to nil, then you can do anything with it, because you can send messages to nil objects.

To put your two lines of code into one, just use the accessor methods:

```
self.object = nil; //this will both release an object and set its pointer to nil
```

Comment: Be mindful when doing this incase your setter has any side effects.

Comment: There, I Fixed It: _No it is not a good practice so set the pointer to nil after releasing the object.  The reason is that if you'd try to access value of that object in future after the object gets deallocated, you'll try to access a garbage value (it's called a dangling pointer) and your application would crash. Because of that crash you would know immediately that you have a memory management bug in your code and you could fix it. But if the pointer is set to nil, you will cover that memory management bug until it causes a crash or malfunction somewhere else._

Comment: Well I must admit, you're right when talking about debugging.

Comment: Look if you feel like being a guru with memory management use self.object = nil. If you're still learning, just use [object release] without setting it to nil, cause it'll help you in debugging.

Comment: You can read about the coding practice of setting the property to nil here: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/20/cocoa-coding-practice-old-school-vs-new/

Comment: *The reason is that if you'd try to access value of that object in future after the object gets deallocated* - this is in the `dealloc` method. So that ivar should not be accessed. Even if it is attempted to be accessed, the object itself is invalid anyway. Setting the ivar to `nil` is (in most cases) pointless in `dealloc`. There are of course cases where you would want to set it to `nil`, but I would say they are the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is the right place to be releasing the object. Obviously only if you're not compiling with ARC enabled though as with ARC you can't even call `release` anyway.
2. There's no real point setting it to `nil`. It's about to be completely destroyed - why bother setting it to `nil`?